# How to fix config file of Hibernate?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I get the error below after executing my java code. It seems that there is a problem with the XML file only. So, I did not post the Java code. The XML code is given after the error. I copied it from my book as is and yet it causes an error. How do i rectify this annoying xml error ?

```
"Some value of time" org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource:     
/hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource:     
 /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper - Error parsing XML:     
/hibernate.cfg.xml(3)     
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse     
configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
    (AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
    (AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
    (AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
    (AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
    (AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
at com.examscam.model.User.persist(User.java:47)
at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:57)
    Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 3 of document  : The markup  
    in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. Nested exception:
    The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1532)
... 9 more
```

The XML file is as follows -

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<!Doctype hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name = "connection.url">
jdbc:mysql://localhost/examscam
</property>

<property name = "connection.username">
root
</property>

<property name = "connection.password">
password
</property>

<property name = "connection.driver_class">
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
</property>

<property name = "dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
</property>

<property name = "transaction.factory_class">
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
</property>

<property name = "current_session_context_class">
thread
</property>

<property name = "hibernate.show_sql">
true
</property>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**EDIT**

```
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource:
 /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: 
/hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : 
com/xx  /portal/db/User.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/xx
/portal/db/User.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:610)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:912)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:617)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
at    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
at com.examscam.model.User.persist(User.java:45)
at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:55)
```

Comment: cfg file from this example also does not work - http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/runninge-xample.shtml

But the project given in this link works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my hibernate configuration file, just check it as following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123456</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <!-- disable cache  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
            false
        </property>

        <!-- UTF8 to database -->
        <property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>

        <!-- C3P0 Session Manager  -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>

        <!-- Entity Mappings -->
        <mapping resource="com/xx/portal/db/User.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Do i need that C3P0 session manager stuff ? My example code does not use it.

Comment: Sorry. Got the same error even with your code. If your xml worked, i would have probably got an error like - your connection url/password/username is not correct, because that is the only difference between my code and your code.

Comment: I have found the difference between yours and mine, please change "<!Doctype"  in hibernate config file to upper case, your application will work well.

Comment: No it cann't, I have tried it myself, when I write as "<!Doctype" I got the same error with you. and then I changed as "<!DOCTYPE" It worked fine. Have you redeployed your project and restarted your server?

Comment: Restarted it. Seems to be working now. I got a new error which i will add to the question. But that is an expected error. I will modify your xml a little and see what happens. Why is this xml so irritating to fix ? Any other ways to do configs ?

Comment: OK, this question is over. please post a new question if there is any other error. please take my answer at first. A good IDE may be a helpful assisant, I use IntelliJ IDEA, see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Made a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057120/hibernate-config-file-is-incorrect