# Hibernate config file is incorrect?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

In an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055067/how-to-fix-config-file-of-hibernate), my hibernate config file had some unknown problem. One person gave me another config file to use and that resolved the old config error. But it also introduced a new error which is given below. How do I fix it ?

**EDIT**

```
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource:
 /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: 
/hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : 
com/xx  /portal/db/User.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: com/xx
/portal/db/User.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:610)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.addResource
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:912)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:617)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1002)
at    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure
(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
at com.examscam.model.User.persist(User.java:45)
at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:55)
```

**I removed "!-- disable cache  --" "!-- UTF8 to database --" "!-- Entity Mappings --" and now i get a new error.**

Comment: Do you have the file /portal/db/User.hbm.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the line `<mapping resource="com/xx/portal/db/User.hbm.xml" />` firstly if you don't have any entity mapping file.

Comment: I removed <!-- disable cache  --> <!-- UTF8 to database --> <!-- Entity Mappings --> and now i get a new error.

Comment: The reason is there is no c3p0.jar in your project library, in your another post you said that you haven't used C3P0, so just remove <!-- C3P0 Session Manager  -->

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i removed that one also, and i am still getting a new error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057649/hibernate-code-is-not-working-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

`com/xx/portal/db/User.hbm.xml` not found

Do you realy have this package name `com/xx`.

Check if you have a `User.hbm.xml` in the mentioned path. If not then remove this entry.

`<mapping resource="com/xx/portal/db/User.hbm.xml" />`

Comment: I removed <!-- disable cache --> <!-- UTF8 to database --> <!-- Entity Mappings --> and now i get a new error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bellow line from your config xml or replace if you have defined any hbms

```
   <!-- Entity Mappings -->
   <mapping resource="com/xx/portal/db/User.hbm.xml" />
```

Comment: I removed <!-- disable cache --> <!-- UTF8 to database --> <!-- Entity Mappings --> and now i get a new error.