# Hibernate code is not working, how to fix?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

In an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055067/how-to-fix-config-file-of-hibernate) , my hibernate config file had some unknown problem. One person gave me another config file to use and that resolved the old config error. After that I removed the code near these comments - **"!-- disable cache  --" "!-- UTF8 to database --" "!-- Entity Mappings --" and now i get a new error.** But it also introduced a new error which is given below. How do I fix it ?

```
org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
[main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 17, 2013 3:10:39 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.examscam.model.User
Apr 17, 2013 3:10:39 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.examscam.model.User on table User
Apr 17, 2013 3:10:39 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
[main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export
[main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider - C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider - Connection properties: {useUnicode=true, user=root, password=****, characterEncoding=UTF-8}
[main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(ManagedProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at com.examscam.model.User.persist(User.java:48)
    at com.examscam.model.User.main(User.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

XML -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            correct url
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Some dependency (jar) seems to be missing.

Comment: Correct url is a real url. So no worries about that one.

Comment: My idiot text book says only 3-4 jars are needed. By now, i have added at least 1000 jars to my project and i still get surprises.

Comment: c3p0-0.9.2.1 was missing. fixed and now the stupid 10 line hibernate code works. Why don't i just use something else if this is how its going to be...shitty xml files, missing jars and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that there is no c3p0.jar in your project library, [click to download](http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/c3p0/c3p0-bin/c3p0-0.9.1/c3p0-0.9.1.bin.zip) and put the c3p0-0.9.x.jar in the zip file into your project lib directory. It'll be OK.

Comment: any alternatives to the shitty xml ? one space error and a whole app can blow sky high. Damn.

Comment: No, there isn't. practice more you'll be used to do.

Answer (score 2):

Add [c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources) this jar to Your classpath.

It seams like `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources` this class is not there in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Beware about newer version of c3p0, I downloaded the latest version (c3p0-0.9.5-pre9) and I get stuck for hours in other errors like:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() 
for servlet default threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
java.lang.AutoCloseable at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass
```

or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources
```

I suggest to download:  [c3p0-0.9.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/) and import all the jar to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a clean build and this problem disappeared. Happened to me after a eclipse heap error. I had to rerun eclipse, kill the tomcat process.